# model always null on submit - mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, http-post

I have a weird problem with mvc4, having a razor view which submits an always null model to it's action, I have searched  for the reason behind that and found a popular reason [here](http://codeblog.shawson.co.uk/mvc-strongly-typed-view-returns-a-null-model-on-post-back/) and [here](http://ideasof.andersaberg.com/idea/9/net-mvc-4-model-binding-null-on-post)

but actually this is invalid in my case, as the action signature is like the following

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Detail(ReleasePaymentEditViewModel model)
```

and have no model field called model
also I've found results talking about populating drop downs issues, but my drop downs are populating correctly in the server side till the render of the view,
so my problem is all about the submit

any one have any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Please post your view code. That's where the problem is probably.

Comment: @shaftpolls: I have a very large view, so i found it a useless to post it here, btw I found the problem and posted it in the answer below, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem ! + 1 to your solution since it's useful and might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in a custom model binder added in the global.asax

```
System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

the class `DecimalModelBinder` inherits the `DefaultModelBinder` found in `System.web.mvc` and it makes issues with normal model binding  on HTTPPost requests

Thank You : )